# Como gerar thumbnails de um bitmap usando AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-eclipse, bitmap, asynctask

Eu tenho um FragmentActivity que possui um listView, em cada item existe um botão para abrir um Dialog, neste Dialog é executado outra listView com um adapter que possui um TextView e um ImageView, a lista vem de um diretório de fotos, queria colocar essas fotos como thumbnails, aquelas miniaturas, eu consegui fazer isso sem usar o AsyncTask, porém, ficou um pouco pesado, pois tenho que comprimir os bitmaps, de acordo com meus estudos, a melhor maneira é usar um AsyncTask para executar o processo pesado, eu fiz isso e ele executa, porém, não aparece o bitmap no respectivo ImageView. Irei colocar o código em ordem.

DialogFragmentListFotos.class

```
public class DialogFragmentListFotos extends DialogFragment {

private ListView listView;
private String path, title;


public static DialogFragmentListFotos newInstance(Bundle bundle) {
    DialogFragmentListFotos f = new DialogFragmentListFotos();
    f.setArguments(bundle);
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog);
    path = getArguments().getString("path");
    title = getArguments().getString("title");
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    String fotosDaOcupacao = getActivity().getString(R.string.fotosDaOcupacao);
    dialog.setTitle(fotosDaOcupacao + " " + title);
    return dialog;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_list_fotos, null);

    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView_fotos);
    Button cancelar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_cancel_list_fotos);

    final File file = new File(path);
    final File[] files = file.listFiles();
    ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<File> fileArrayList = new ArrayList<File>();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        stringArrayList.add(files[i].getName());
        fileArrayList.add(files[i]);
    }
    //ArrayAdapter<String> filesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item, theNamesOfFiles);
    ArrayAdapter<File> filesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapterFotos(getActivity(), R.layout.adapter_d_list_fotos, fileArrayList);

    cancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });

    listView.setAdapter(filesArrayAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            File file = new File(path + "/" + files[position].getName());
            String type = getType(file);
            Intent it = new Intent();
            it.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            it.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);

            try {
                getActivity().startActivity(it);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                String appNessNaoEncontrado = getActivity().getString(R.string.appNessNaoEncontrado);
                ToastManager.show(getActivity(), appNessNaoEncontrado, ToastManager.ERROR, ToastManager.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}

private String getType(File file) {
    String type = null;
    try {
        URL u = file.toURL();
        URLConnection uc = null;
        uc = u.openConnection();
        type = uc.getContentType();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return type;
}
}
```

ArrayAdapterFotos.class

```
public class ArrayAdapterFotos extends ArrayAdapter<File> {

private final int resourceId;
private ArrayList<File> files;
private Context context;
private int pos;
public ImageView imageView;

public ArrayAdapterFotos(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<File> files) {
    super(context, resource, files);
    this.resourceId = resource;
    this.files = files;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.i("Posição", String.valueOf(position));
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(resourceId, parent, false);
    }
    pos = position;
    imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_foto_thumbail);
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_nome_foto);
    textView.setText(files.get(position).getName());

    BitmapTask bitmapTask = new BitmapTask();
    bitmapTask.execute(files.get(position).getAbsolutePath());

    return convertView;
}

public class BitmapTask extends AsyncTask<String, Bitmap, Bitmap> {

    private String data;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        int h = 48; // height in pixels
        int w = 48; // width in pixels
        data = params[0];
        Bitmap bitmap =       ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(data), h, w);
        publishProgress(bitmap);
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap... values) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: jah pensou em umsa uma lib para os thumbs? https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/THUMBNAIL.md https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Tenta isso.

Remova a declaração public `ImageView imageView;` do adapter

Adicion o código para:

```
//adicione esse atributo no seu adapter
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

//adicione dentro do constutor este trecho de código
public ArrayAdapterFotos(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<File> files) {
    //...
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount() {
    return files.size();
}
public File getItem(int position) {
    return files.get(position);
}
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ItemSuporte itemHolder;
     if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = mInflater.inflate(resourceId, null);
          itemHolder = new ItemSuporte();
          itemHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_foto_thumbail);
          itemHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_nome_foto);
          convertView.setTag(itemHolder);
     }else{
          //se a view já existe pega os itens.
        itemHolder = (ItemSuporte) convertView.getTag();
     }
    itemHolder.textView.setText(files.get(position).getName());

    BitmapTask bitmapTask = new BitmapTask(itemHolder.imageView);
    bitmapTask.execute(files.get(position).getAbsolutePath());
   //...
}
private class BitmapTask extends AsyncTask<String, Bitmap, Bitmap> {
    private ImageView imageView
    private String data;

    public BitmapTask(ImageView imageView){
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }
    //...
}

private class ItemSuporte {

    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView textView;

}
```

Comment: Agora aparece as fotos! Porém aconteceu algo esquisito, ele carrega as imagens no primeiro item da listview, mostrando todas as imagens como se fosse quadro a quadro, depois disso ele carrega as imagens em toda a listView, já retirei  o onProgressUpdate do AsyncTask e ainda continua com isso.

Comment: Você precisa criar uma classe de suporte, você esta declarando o ImageView dentro do adapter, assim o imageView fica global, voce tem que ter um ImageView para cada item da lista. Vou ajustar a resposta.

Comment: para voce entender e funcionar faça isso dentro do getView: 
`ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_foto_thumbail);`

Comment: Depois da sua resolução eu fiz isso, retirei a declaração global do ImageView e coloquei exatamente como você fez, mas o problema ai fica o mesmo.

Comment: ImageView thumbImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_foto_thumbail);

Comment: eu to elaborando aqui possivelmente pode ter erro no código conforme eu for encontrando eu vvo ajustando. Ve se dessa forma funciona.

Comment: Ok, fico grato pela ajuda e sua disposição, porém, continua com o mesmo problema, mesmo com está solução.